# ng-disabled overrides custom directive behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing the AngularJS client. I've got a custom directive used as an attribute. The directive checks the access level of the element and sets it to be disabled if the current user is not allowed to use it.

The problem begins when the same element has `ng-disabled` attribute. In this case the `ng-disabled` sets the ability of the element, never mind of what I set in my custom directive.

**For example** I have a button that should be disabled in case the form is invalid. At the same time I'd like to use my custom directive in order to set the button to be disabled if the user doesn't have a permition to use it.

```
<button ng-disabled="myFrm.myCtrl.$invalid" my-custom-directive="controlName"/>
```

Inside `myCustomDirective` I check if the named control is allowed to be activated by the user. If not - I set the disabled attribute to the element. But in case  `myFrm.myCtrl.$invalid` is false  `ng-disabled` removes the disabled attribute and the button is enabled.

Is there any solution to this problem? How can I prevent from ng-disabled to perform its operation?

Comment: Sharing some code would help in quick resolution

Comment: Not sure if its a good idea, but can we not pass `myFrm.myCtrl` into that directive and accordingly set some boolean value in `$scope` which can then be *watched* by `ng-disabled`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I've found a solution to my problem. Instead of watching ng-disabled variable I've totaly diconnected the ng-disabled from its variable. In order to do it I've set the ng-disabled to be allways true in my own directive. My directive is an attribute, so after I've tried some different ways to do it, the solution was to add in my directive constructor the following code:

```
this.isDisabled = "true";
this.attrs["ngDisabl​ed"] = this.isDisabled;
```

It's very very important to set the this.isDisabled to "true" as a string and not boolean. Otherwise it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Does your example directive reflect how you applied your actual directive to the button element? I noticed that your example directive is not following the correct naming convention of making each upper case letter in the directive name a lower case letter with a leading hyphen. i.e. myCustomDirective should be applied to the button like so:

> ```
> <button ng-disabled="myFrm.myCtrl.$invalid" my-custom-directive="controlName"/>
> ```

Otherwise your directive will not be complied or linked for that button.

The only other thing I could think of without seeing the actual code is the priority of the directive. According to the angular docs for [the ngDisabled directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled):

> This directive executes at priority level 100.

By default custom directives have a priority of 0. As long as you have not changed this directive parameter your directive should be compiled after ng-disabled and linked after ng-disabled and therefore have the final say on whether or not the button is disabled or enabled.

-- EDIT --
You should add a watch to myFrm.myCtrl.$invalid as was suggested by another and reapply your directives rules whenever the value changes. You don't need to pass the whole controller into your directive though, you could simply use two way binding on myFrm.myCtrl.$invalid. I am not sure how $watch priority works yet. I am hoping that because your directive will be compiled first it will apply its watch on myFrm.myCtrl.$invalid after ngDisabled does and hopefully that means it will handle value changes of myFrm.myCtrl.$invalid after ngDisable does so that your directive has the final say on what rule is applied.

Comment: Hi @dustfinger , thanks for your reply. Of course you are right, the case of my custom directive name in the example is wrong. It's not the real code example so it not the issure. I'll edit this point inside my question.

Comment: I've also tried the solution you've suggested. It does not work. The problem is that the ng-disabled has its own watch on the variable. It is registered to the watch bofore my custom directive does, but my watch function is activated before. For some reason, Angular in its digest circle activates the watch registered functions from the end to the beginning, oposite to the registration order. I'll try to change the directive priority.